phantom approval question
hi i’m scanning a token and a critical error comes up regarding this part of the code
receive() external payable {}
description of vulnerability:
PHANTOM PERMIT
The contract’s token transfer mechanism is vulnerable. The issue stems from the interaction inside the  function. permit() function is used to transfer tokens on behalf of someone else for gasless transactions. The vulnerability arises when the given token is not implementing the permit() function, such as WETH, stETH, and BNB, which triggers the fallback function and in this fallback function the revert mechanism is not implemented. This returns true for every call of the permit() function.
While clients think they are secure by approving transactions only when they initiate them, this vulnerability allows an attacker to deposit funds belonging to someone else, given that the phantom permit call doesn't fail.
can anyone help me out here??

Am not clear on the question? It makes sense that having a fallback that always returns true, allows for sending permit calldata that silently fails. But I'm how having a receive function and no fallback would allow for permit data to pass, if receive only accepts 0 data calls. If it's just a simple scan maybe it lacks context, else might need more specifics of the implementation.

hi Maka. yes it’s a simple scan i was wondering would this with a wETH pair create a vulnerability? it has no withdraw function but my simple scan says it’s a critical vulnerability to have that in the contract.

Working on an answer, just to clarify does weth pair mean uniswap style pool token?

yes so token/weth pair.
